# Managing user level customizations to a run configuration stored as a project file

Tags: intellij-idea

In my java project, we have a Intellij IDEA run configuration stored as a project file, which is tracked in VCS.

But, there can be user level customizations to this run config by each user, which they have to keep as a local change in the VCS, which they should omit from their regular commits.

Is there a way to manage the local customizations to the run config without having to keep a local change in VCS, for an example in a user level override file which is ignored in VCS?

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism for that. I would instruct users to make a copy of the configuration and modify it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I also considered that option, but the project is not very stable yet, so the shared config keeps changing frequently. So if I keep a user level copy, I will have to update it whenever the shared config changes.

Comment: A feature request would be welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder feature request created. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-305128/Ability-to-override-run-configurations-stored-as-project-files-at-user-level